# Sitecore does note render Media item Title field

Tags: image, sitecore, rendering, media

I just noticed, Sitecore does not render all the fields of Media item to HTML.  For example, image item renders only **AltText** and doesn't "**Title**" field.
In the output page ***< img >*** tag does not show "**Title**" Attribute.

Is this a bug?  Any workaround how to render **Title** attribute.  Will it cause any issues to SEO factors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Title" field isn't meant to correspond to the "title" attribute. However, you can apply attributes to the rendered image tag anyway, and assuming you have a method for getting the media item it'd look something like this:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("fieldName", item, new { title = item.GetMediaItem("fieldName").Title })
```